# nativescript - why should i use xmlns url in <Page> tag?

Tags: nativescript

I'm starting learning of Nativescript. I bought some books to learn, and i'm also checking official tutorial. On most of official tutorials i see that in view file i may have :

```
<Page loaded="loaded"></Page>
```

But sometimes i see additional tag, like:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"loaded="pageLoaded"></Page>
```

My question is: what is a valid way ?

Also, if possible to sort this:
What is valid setup of page structure setup:

app

-- main-page.xml

-- main-page.js

-- main-page.css

OR (i saw this in one of books - it's called 'view behind'):
app
-- main-page.xml

-- main-page.js

-- main-page.css

-- main-page-model.js - is this one valid ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD schema describes the structure of an XML document. It is always good practice to include the XSD schema namespace to ensure that your NativeScript XML has a valid structure as per NativeScript structure.

The second part of your question is showing two different scenarios:

- the first one  has layout (**main-page.xml**), code-behind file (**main-page.js**) and the CSS file (**main-page.css**)
- the second one lacks the layout (main-page.xml) which suggests that the layouts are created dynamically in the code-behind file. The file **main-view-model.js** is suggesting that the specific application is using **MVVM** (**Model-View-ViewModel**) and this is the ViewModel file. The pattern is commonly used in NativeScript Core applications. More about **MVVM in NativeScript** can be found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-3#chapter-3application-logic)